# Qual é a aplicabilidade do problema das 8 rainhas?

Tags: ciência-da-computação

Na faculdade o professor de programação linear apresentou o Problema das 8 Rainhas.

Basicamente, pelo que entendi, este problema consiste em preencher o tabuleiro (poderia ser simulado com uma matriz) com as 8 rainhas de uma forma que o numero de ataques de cada rainha seja igual `0` zero. As rainhas podem atacar na horizontal, vertical e diagonal, senão me engano.

Sendo assim, eu até compreendi um pouco o problema das 8 rainhas, contudo, este problema me gerou mais dúvidas a respeito dele mesmo e da computação.

## Dúvidas

1. Que tipo de situação o Problema das 8 Rainhas tenta abordar no mundo
   real? Ou qual seria a aplicabilidade dele?
2. Qual é a relação do Problema das 8 Rainhas com a programação linear?
3. Existe limitações computacionais na solução deste problema? Se sim, quais?

Comment: Dá uma lida aí http://conteudo.icmc.usp.br/pessoas/sandra/G6_t2/rainha.htm

Comment: Possivelmente é uma adaptação do problema de coloração de grafos.

Comment: relacionada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/285412/70

Comment: Isso me lembra que posso ficar rico: https://olhardigital.com.br/fique_seguro/noticia/desafio-paga-us-1-milhao-ao-criador-de-software-que-resolve-problema-de-xadrez/70798

Comment: @Everson vai fundo! Fique rico e dedique todo o seu tempo a ficar postando conteúdo no SOpt xD

Answer (score 6):

O problema das n-rainhas pode ser reduzido ao problema de SAT(satisfabilidade), que é um problema NP-Completo.
E o problema mais famoso de SAT é o de achar uma configuração das variáveis para satisfazer uma expressão booleana.

Por exemplo, encontrar valores de A, B, C, D e E de forma que a seguinte expressão seja satisfeita:`A and B and C or D and E`.

As aplicações desse problema são várias na vida real.
Uma delas é fazer uma aplicação que faça alocação de turmas de forma que nenhuma turma tenha aula na mesma sala ao mesmo tempo.
Ou então um plano de viagem, no qual `n` aviões não podem estar sobrevoando a mesma área ao mesmo tempo.

Normalmente para resolver esse tipo de problema são utilizados algoritmos de busca local, no qual o caminho para a solução não importa, o que importa simplesmente é o estado final no qual representa uma solução.
Por exemplo, se eu estou fazendo uma aplicação de alocação de turmas, eu nao quero saber quais foram os estados intermediários durante a computação da solução, eu só quero saber o último estado, que representa a solução. A mesma coisa se aplica no problema das n-rainhas, eu não quero saber os estados intermediários, eu só quero saber um estado no qual ninguém se ataque.

A programação linear pode ser brevemente resumida em: Dado um conjunto de restrições, encontrar a melhor solução possível dentro desse contexto.
Que é justamente o que estamos tentando fazer no problema nas n-rainhas.

Esse link aqui tem uma explicação e implementação bacana:
https://sites.google.com/site/haioushen/search-algorithm/solvean-queensproblemusingsatsolver